# service.acknowledge is undefined using Digital Goods API with Google Play in TWA

Tags: android, google-play, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, payment-request-api

I have an web app in development to which I am trying to add Google Play Billing on Android and Chrome OS.  My implementation is basically the same as in [Google's own documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/receive-payments-play-billing/), however it fails at the point of acknowledging the purchase after it completes, throwing `TypeError: service.acknowledge is not a function`.  Everything else works fine, but not being able to acknowledge the purchase means Google Play automatically reverses it after a period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that is because they changed the API and just [have not yet updated that page of documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/1631).  Apparently `service.acknowledge` was removed, and they now require passing the purchase token to your own back-end, and then having *that* call the Google Play Developer API to acknowledge the purchase.

Unfortunately, that does not seem likely to change, so options like Cordova continue to be the best option for client-only web apps with in-app purchases for the moment.